# Adding NaN values comparing with another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a dataframe df_a as -

```
Date         Quantity
2019-02-01     345
2019-02-09     570
2019-03-10     784
2019-03-19     880
2019-04-05    1134
2019-05-12    1477
2019-07-21    2190
```

whereas, another one that starts midway as df_b

```
Date         Quantity
2019-03-19    1840
2019-04-05    2149
2019-05-12    2473
2019-07-21    2992
```

How can I modify this dataframe to have NaN values for the first 3 dates as I need to plot this data and compare both lines? Expected output -

```
Date         Quantity
2019-02-01     NaN
2019-02-09     NaN
2019-03-10     NaN
2019-03-19    1840
2019-04-05    2149
2019-05-12    2473
2019-07-21    2992
```

But, when I plot it now, it shows df_b values as starting from 2019-02-01 instead of 2019-03-19, i.e the plot doesn't start midway as it should.

Comment: You could merge df_b onto df_a with a left join

Comment: `pd.merge(df_b, df_a, on='Date', how='outer').drop(columns='Quantity_y').sort_values('Date')`

Answer (score 1):

So you can do `reindex` after `set_index`

```
df2.set_index('Date').reindex(df1.Date).reset_index()
Out[14]: 
         Date  Quantity
0  2019-02-01       NaN
1  2019-02-09       NaN
2  2019-03-10       NaN
3  2019-03-19    1840.0
4  2019-04-05    2149.0
5  2019-05-12    2473.0
6  2019-07-21    2992.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a single frame containing both?

```
df_a = df_a.set_index('Date')
df_b = df_b.set_index('Date')

df_a['QuantityB] = db_b['Quantity']
```